# How to define a generic type in function calling rather than function defining

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function `function react_forward_ref<P, T>(fn: (props: P, ref: T) => any) { return fn }` where `P` has nothing to do with `T`.

Now I want to use it and make the `P and T` in its return value have some relation like `T = Parameters<typeof OBJ[P]>[0]`, so I write:

```
const OBJ = {
    a: (_: number) => _,
    b: (_: string) => _,
    c: (_: object) => _,
}
const MyCom = (<P extends keyof typeof OBJ>() => {
    return react_forward_ref<P, Parameters<typeof OBJ[P]>[0]>((props, ref) => null)
})()
```

My expected behavior is:

```
const MyCom = function<P extends keyof typeof OBJ>(props: P, ref: Parameters<typeof OBJ[P]>[0]) { return null }
```

But the current behavior is:

```
const MyCom = function(props: keyof typeof OBJ, ref: Parameters<typeof OBJ[keyof typeof OBJ]>[0]) { return null }
```

**The old question:**

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA8gIQFIwLwwN4FgBQN8wCGAXDABQD6pYArgLYBGApgE4CUaAfDBQDS4EYDUpVLQWASzABzDqm58BBYCKowQDAFZNgUOQv44AvrlwAzGmF0TwMFk0K6KZkCwDuhFgBMK9swB4ABV4YABVOMjMwEQAHFhAYiFJguyYzUlD9IjAATw4MVKgaFjAYKJgTHFxQSFgAWRyAYRA6NHJ-UJgmAA8oJjAvCBgAayYckDMYKByYpgn4ZAis7DwCeyKS1McoZ1cPb180jpDAz0I6Jj6WCH9p2fnEJABtUIBdTieABneyMjiEiAhPxZWgAG1BbFwRjYZEhOAA9PCYBJYBAABYgGigrwwMAgWAxQgQCC4UGXIhtBrNOhkADkhFpIVpUDREiG6Mx2JgdBo0CETAptEYrBCDBosCgQz64KGF2RsGAhFKzAp4ik0lpbAA3KYEUiWWzkUNJNI0VBquA+VSWp82h0ur1+oMRmN5nc5pNHhF-okMkC0skzhcrjd3Q9kC93l9XssKrhrXRPnSGUzJVMmDLuQKUdzebAVYRcfRmCxNUA

```
const OBJ = {
    a: (_: number) => _,
    b: (_: string) => _,
    c: (_: object) => _,
}

function react_forward_ref<P, T>(fn: (props: P, ref: T) => any) { return fn }

const MyCom = (<T extends keyof typeof OBJ>() => {
    return react_forward_ref<T, Parameters<typeof OBJ[T]>[0]>((props, ref) => null)
})()
// ts works wrong here
let a = MyCom('a', 'this should must be a number, but ts tells me it can be a string');

// ts works right here
const MyCom0 = <T extends keyof typeof OBJ>(props: T, ref: Parameters<typeof OBJ[T]>[0]) => { }
MyCom0('a', 'ts tells me it must be a number')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you provide explicit type to MyCom, it works as expected

```js
// does not compile
let a = MyCom<'a'>()('a', 'this should must be a number, but ts tells me it can be a string')()
```

Answer (score 0):

`react_forward_ref` has two generic type declaration.

I have a function `OriginMyCom` which need to be wrapped in `react_forward_ref`, and it need to bind the two generic type declaration together.

So I used to thought that I need to declare a generic type before `react_forward_ref`'s two generic type to bind them together.

But now, it turns out that I can:

```
const OBJ = {
  a: (_: number) => _,
  b: (_: string) => _,
  c: (_: object) => _,
}

function react_forward_ref<P, T>(fn: (props: P, ref: T) => any) { return fn }

const OriginMyCom = <P extends keyof typeof OBJ>(p: P, ref: (typeof OBJ)[P]) => null;

const ForwardedMyCom = react_forward_ref(OriginMyCom);
```

That's because **Generic Type is generic**. It's something like `let a = 123;` in which the `generic type` is `a` and the `real type` is `123`. It's like `left value and right value`. We must notice it.

**So to bind two generic type together, we should declare a generic type as the relation after rather than before the two generic type.**